# How to specifically assign function differently to two inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, spectrum

I am having an issue I cannot figure out regarding assigning a specific function to an input. I created a color picker with two different color options (inputs). Each one adds color to a different div. In what I have created, I do not understand how I can control which input assigns the color to the outside or inside div. As you can see in my fiddle, I have the inner color input first and that changes the outside color and vise versa for the other div.

I am wanting to be able to control the inputs, so they assign the color to the div I am wanting.

What am I doing wrong?

[The Spectrum docs](http://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/)

[See Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/9/)

```
$(".colorpicker").spectrum({
    color: "#FFF",
    showInput: true,
    className: "full-spectrum",
    showInitial: true,
    showPalette: true,
    showSelectionPalette: true,
    maxSelectionSize: 10,
    preferredFormat: "hex",
    localStorageKey: "spectrum.demo",
    change: function(color) {
        var eq =  $(this).index('.colorpicker');
      $('.container').eq(eq).css('background-color', color.toHexString())
    }
```

Inside Color
    
  
  Outside Color

If I chose orange for the outside color, how can I continue to use and set that color for other divs inside of the outside div?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/way4LmbL/12/

```
<div id="control-container">
<label for="outside" class="color-label">Outside Color
    <input type="text" name="outside" class="colorpicker">
  </label>
  <label for="inside" class="color-label" id="inside-color-label">Inside Color
    <input type="text" name="inside" class="colorpicker">
  </label>

</div>
```

Actually the problem is with the change event, where you are finding the index of the color picker and then assigning it to the background color of the corresponding index of the container class.

Comment: Yes, that is how I originally had it, but changed it due to both the inside and outside colors changing initially when the outside color is set.

Comment: that is because in css background property inherit the parents value i mean css rule, that is why outside div color setting the color to inside div also, if you don't want that then you have to change the div structure and try to use position property to give the same look and feel to your page

Comment: Is there anyway around this? What I am looking to do is add other children div to the outside div. I am then wanting to assign these other divs one of the colors I chose. For an example see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to switch your two Colorpickers like so:

```
<div id="control-container">
    <label for="outside" class="color-label">Outside Color
        <input type="text" name="outside" class="colorpicker">
    </label>  
    <label for="inside" class="color-label" id="inside-color-label">Inside Color
        <input type="text" name="inside" class="colorpicker">
    </label>
</div>
```

This way the index of the colorpicker matches the index of the `.container`you want to set the background-color in.

Comment: Yes, that is how I originally had it, but changed it due to both the inside and outside colors changing initially when the outside color is set.